# assembly find words that contain substring in given string

Tags: string, assembly, substring

i'm trying to write a script in assembly lang. that prints words with substring from given string.
for example:

```
char* a="hello world   lol  asdf";
char* b="lo";
char buffer[100];
```

and the printed words are :

"hello lol"

i wrote program in ANSI C for that:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){

    char *s = "hello bencsss trololo molo";
    char *b ="lo";
    char bufor[100];
    int i, j=0,k=0,c=0,l=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        if(s[i]==' ') k=i+1;

        if(b[j]==s[i]){
            j++;
            if(j==strlen(b)-1){
                while(s[k]!=' ' && k<(strlen(s))){
                bufor[c]=s[k];
                    c++;
                    k++;
                }
            bufor[c]=' ';
            c++;
            k=i;
            }
        }
        else{
        j=0;    
        }
    }
    printf("%s",bufor);
    return 0;   
}
```

and here is what i wrote so far in asm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    //short int y;
    char *s = "hello world!\n"; 
    char *b ="lo";
    char bufor[100];

    asm volatile(
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"   
    "mov eax,%0;" //16
    "push eax;"
    "mov eax,%1;" //12
    "push eax;"
    "mov eax,%2;" //8
    "call zadanie1;"
    "jmp end;"
"zadanie1:"
    "push eax;"
    "push ebp;" //4
    "mov ebp,esp;"
    "push ebx;"
    "push ecx;"
    "push edx;"

    "mov ebx,[esp+16];"
"reset:"
    "mov eax,[esp+12];"
    "jmp word;"
"space:"
    "mov [si],ebx;"
    "jmp forward;"
"word:"
    "mov dl,[ebx];"
    "mov dh,[eax];"
    "cmp dl,' ';"
    "je space;"
"forward:"
    "cmp dl,dh;"
    "inc ebx;"
    "jz reset;"
    "inc eax;"       
    "cmp dh,'0';"
    "je buff;"
    "jmp word;"
"buff:"
    "mov [ecx,esp+8];"
    "inc ecx;"
"loop:"
    "mov dh,[ecx];"
    "mov [si],dh"   
    "cmp dh,' ';"
    "je reset;"
    "inc ecx;"
    "inc si;"




    "end:"
    ".att_syntax prefix;"
    :
    :"r"(s), "r"(b),"r"(bufor) 
    :"eax"

    );
```

asm might be written wrong and it's not finished, i'm still newbe in this language so..

Ok... could i get any words or advice or something how to make this program in asm, please? 
took me 3 day to write this so far... and now i'm out of ideas how to make it actually work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next instructions are not correct.

```
"mov ebx,[esp+16];"
"mov eax,[esp+12];"
```

Use EBP in stead of ESP to process your parameters.

This syntax does not exist. What do aim to accomplish?

```
"mov [ecx,esp+8];"
```

What do you think the `jz reset` will act upon? The ZF defined after `cmp dl,dh` is destroyed by `inc ebx`.

```
"cmp dl,dh;"
"inc ebx;"
"jz reset;"
```